# What are the best modules in Drupal 7 to use for caching via Varnish, memcached, APC, etc? And is Pressflow still relevant in a D7 world?

Tags: drupal, caching, memcached, varnish, pressflow

First of all I'm a bit confused as to what is really included with Pressflow. Is Pressflow just a collection of modules or are there some deeper core hacks that aren't in D7? Would it be a reasonable solution to keep on going with our D7 install and adding the appropriate caching modules?

I understand that Drupal 7 works with Varnish out of the box, but then it also benefits from the Varnish module in some way. I'm curious about whether there's a killer-combo that people have generally converged on.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/what-are-the-key-differences-between-drupal-7-and-pressflow-7 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18313/migrating-to-pressflow

Answer (score 1):

Check this video: http://drupalize.me/videos/overview-performance-scalability.

Nathan Hauge explains that there aren't benefits to using Pressflow 6 instead of Drupal 7. In fact, Content Delivery Networks, reverse proxy and slave data base servers improvements in Pressflow 6 has been implemented in Drupal 7 too. Pressflow 6 was a great alternative to improve Drupal 6 performance and scalability; it is also a good option if you plan to use Drupal 6 modules that don't work in Drupal 7. If you are starting a project from scratch, starting with Drupal 7 is recommended.

Maybe in the future Pressflow will be updated, and will make improvements to Drupal 7 performance and scalability; for now, Drupal 7 is a good option.